# How to execute (some) CGI commands as root

Tags: apache-2.2, root, users, cgi

I want to put a simple CGI script in my APACHE server.
I'd like to write it possibly in C (but also in PERL, if I want).

The problem is that it must contain some lines that can be executed only by root (`iptables` for example), while webuser is the user running the server.

How can I make those lines executable by the root?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution might be  to write a wrapper script for the relevant commands, heavily secure this script and allow a passwordless sudo for this.

Edit: A wrapper script is just some short shell script where you offload the critical commands. You can secure this (e.g. make it aceessible only be the Apache user).

For sudo, there are many questions already on Serverfault and elsewhere, also there is a man page for it: `man sudo` and `man sudoers`.

If you have difficulties with this after reading the available docs, you could still ask a question specific to your problem.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I don't know how to do either of those things (wrapper script, passwordless sudo), but maybe I should ask different questions?

Comment: @JustTrying: See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) on the script.  An executable with **setuid** executes as the owner for any normal user.  (`/bin/ping` for example.)

Be **very**, **very** careful with this.  Make sure the script cannot be overwritten with malicious code, etc.

[man setuid](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setuid)

Comment: Thank you. If I'm not wrong, I can use `setuid` only if I write the CGI in C, right?

Comment: I think it works for any executable, as that's how the documentation is written.  It doesn't say it specifically has to be a binary.  (But admittedly, I didn't test it and have only experience with setuid binaries.)

Comment: "Due to the increased likelihood of security flaws, many operating systems ignore the setuid attribute when applied to executable shell scripts."  Well, it says *might*, so you might have some luck, or you might be able to enable it.  Either way, it might not be recommended.  People way smarter than me came up with the limitation.